# Amazon.S3.IO S3DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload files to Amazon S3 (official SDK) that are larger than 5 MB (approx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871430/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-official-sdk-that-are-larger-than-5-mb-appro)

I try to use the Amazon.S3.IO API. If i write 10mb there is no problem. If i write 21mb i get an exception:

> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
>
> StackTRace:
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
>    at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
>    at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>    at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
>    at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getRequestStreamCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)
>    at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
>    at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndPutObject(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>    at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.PutObject(PutObjectRequest request)
>    at Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToS3)
>    at Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
>    at S3FileSystem_Sample.Program.createFile(S3DirectoryInfo rootDirectory, String  filename) in c:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\Samples\S3FileSystem_Sample \S3FileSystem_Sample\Program.cs:line 106
>    at S3FileSystem_Sample.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\Samples\S3FileSystem_Sample\S3FileSystem_Sample\Program.cs:line 59
>    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

```
static void createFile(S3DirectoryInfo rootDirectory, string filename)
{ 

    // Creates a file at the root of the bucket.
    S3FileInfo readme = rootDirectory.GetFile(filename);
    char[] buffer = new char[buffersize];  
    fillBuffer(buffer);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readme.OpenWrite()))
    {              

        writer.Write(buffer);

    }
}
```

Any idea i could set the timeout?

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871430/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-official-sdk-that-are-larger-than-5-mb-appro) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408458/cannot-upload-files-larger-than-30mb-to-amazon?rq=1) for more related questions.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the answer of the first question you link ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3871531/428236

Comment: I want to use the Amazon.S3.IO API because it's a more simplier implementation and matches perfecty with existing interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the Amazon.S3.IO API does not support setting a timeout but as a Developer on the SDK I will add that feature request to our backlog.

Keep in mind the Amazon.S3.IO API is a really easy interface to work with S3 but it is not well suited for large files because it buffers them into memory until you have passed the entire contents of the file to the API and then it writes it to S3.  For large files you should use the TransferUtility found in the the Amazon.S3.Transfer namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May i suggest to think about changing/providing the S3FileStream class, which could use a configurable range to download a file. I think Azure did implement it with the class BlobStream.